# Retrieve comments on Facebook ads through the API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Is it even possible to retrieve comments on Facebook ads through the API (Graph or FQL)? If yes, do I need a whitelisted app to do it? Also, if I have a page access token, is it enough, or I need a user access token with ads_management permission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get comments from facebook ads (marketing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931380/get-comments-from-facebook-ads-marketing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pull the actual words of the comment via the API - would make it too easy to scrape.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the token usage, a `page_token` is extended by a given user to a given app. The page_token will have at most the same privileges as the user on his authorized pages and ad_accounts.

Generating a page_token can be done automatically, in behalf of the user, if you already have a `user_token` with `manage_pages` permission. Again, this `page_token` will have at most the same privileges that the `user_token` you used to generate it.

In other words, having a `page_token` doesn't amount for any additional privileges than the ones already present in the `user_token`.

Having said that, you need

1. a token with access to a given ad_account
2. that the app for which that token was generated, has that ad_account active in its settings

If the second requisite isn't met, for example for  `ad_account` `act_123456789` you'll get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account 123456789 not enabled for this application.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 274,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxx"
  }
}
```

You can try, for example, generating a token with all privileges for the  [Graph API Explorer App](http://tps://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). It will throw the error above because said App doesn't have the ad_account `act_123456789` enabled.

So, given you have a token with `ads_read` extended for an app that has this ad_account listed, and you know the `ad_id`, you can procede as I explained  in thread [Get comments from facebook ads (marketing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931380/get-comments-from-facebook-ads-marketing/45745296#45745296)

Basically, you use the ad_id (for example `123000000`) to get the promoted post id and its actions

/123000000?fields=creative.fields(effective_object_story_id),insights.fields(actions)

The answer will contain an `effective_object_story_id` (for example, let's say it is `456000000_789000000`) and its actions broken down by type:

```
{
  "creative": {
    "effective_object_story_id": "456000000_789000000",
    "id": "123000000"
  },
  "insights": {
    "data": [
      {
        "actions": [
          {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "12"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "like",
            "value": "2"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "29"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "video_view",
            "value": "558"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "604"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "602"
          }
        ],
        "date_start": "2017-08-14",
        "date_stop": "2017-08-20"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "xxx",
        "after": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to also distinguish paid comments from regular comments, you can query the `comments` edge of the post_id `456000000_789000000` to get the overall comment count which should be greater than the comments generated by the ad.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Facebook ads that have comments are because the ad is a promoted page post, whether that page post is hidden or not. Page post comments are available via the Facebook API and does not require having Ads API access. Use the graph API endpoint /v2.1/{page-id}/comments to retreive page post comments. See the [Facebook Graph API documentation on object comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/comments) for more information.