# Get comments from facebook ads (marketing)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-java-api

After I make an ads for my post on facebook ads manager.
Facebook Ads Manager show me how many comment belong to this ads. This is very important for me to verify the effective of my campaign.

In programing aspect: Is there's any way to count number belong to my ads like Facebook Ads Manager (I describe above). I have used both Java Facebook Ads SDK (Ads Insight module from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk) and Graph Explorer Tool, they both return "comment" field or "like" field not existed
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can't get comments nor reactions from Marketing Insights directly.</strike>

I stand corrected. If you have access to an ad_account insights, then you can use Marketing API to get a post's comments directly. Thanks @lamxung55

Let's say you have and ad_id of `123000000`

If you have a token with `ads_management` or `ads_read` permission, you can make a request to the Marketing API such as

```
/123000000?fields=creative.fields(effective_object_story_id),insights.fields(actions)
```

This will give you the `effective_object_story_id` which is the `object_id` of the post (`{page_id}_{post_id}`), and its insights including its actions broken down by action type. For example:

```
{
  "creative": {
    "effective_object_story_id": "456000000_789000000",
    "id": "123000000"
  },
  "insights": {
    "data": [
      {
        "actions": [
          {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "12"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "like",
            "value": "2"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "29"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "video_view",
            "value": "558"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "604"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "602"
          }
        ],
        "date_start": "2017-08-14",
        "date_stop": "2017-08-20"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "xxx",
        "after": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `effective_object_story_id` (so, post_id) is `456000000_789000000`.

You can then query the `comments` edge of the post adding `summary=true` as a parameter. This endpoint is public for common posts (however, it won't work for non public posts)

```
/456000000_789000000/comments?summary=true
```

Which will respond with an object like

```
{
  "data": [
     <LOTS OF COMMENTS HERE>
  ],
  "paging": {
    <PAGING LINKS>
  },
  "summary": {
    "order": "chronological",
    "total_count": 50,
    "can_comment": true
  }
}
```

This means the post has had 50 comments, of which 12 were made through a paid action.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail answer. We can simply use this syntax to get adset comment: ...adset_id/insights?fields=actions.

Comment: You might be right, I will check it out tomorrow. Last time I tried the actions breakdown was misleading and didn't match the value on the page dashboard. 
When building a report, one has to make sure that metrics are consistent, and you often need to dig through the metrics to find out when it is a valid result vs a result that might be counting duplicate people, or comments in a story that is a share of your post.

Comment: @lamxung55 I stand corrected. With your suggestion you can, actually, retrieve paid comments which is different from total post comments.

Comment: Yes you, I want to get comments which belong to my ads campaign (not total comment), this is a important factor of the campaign's efffective

Comment: One more problem, all insight datas we get via graph are not synchronized with facebook ads manager (FB backend dashboard). Delayed about 6h than FB ads manager. How can we get realtime data

Comment: @lamxung55 I doubt that can be done, mate. Querying ads stats specifying a timespan (period parameter) is described as `from the starting midnight of the "since" parameter to the ending midnight of the "until" parameter`. If your "until" is the current day I'm not sure how much delay it has in comparison to the Ads Manager.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use this syntax to get adset comment: ...adset_id/insights?fields=actions. Another ads stuffs are the same