# How to get AD_ACCOUNT_ID for read comments under Instagram ads?

Tags: instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api, instagram-graph-api

I know that for getting comments under Instagram Ads I need to use `effective_object_story_id/comments` ([Get comments from facebook ads (marketing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931380/get-comments-from-facebook-ads-marketing)). For get `effective_object_story_id` I need to know `AD_ACCOUNT_ID`.

How to find AD_ACCOUNT_ID if I know `Instagram Account ID` and connected `Business Page ID`?

I tried to find information in docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ but ineffectually.